# Background process without influence of Routing in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, web-applications, background-process, angular-routing

I'm developing a Angular (Version 7.2.x) web application and in that I'm having multiple components and each component is associate with an route.

**Component #1: `ProcessDataComponent`**

In this component, I'm doing a HTTP call to the server. This call will take approx a minute to complete and it will return the result file as `OctetStream` (i.e., `ArrayBuffer`) as a HTTP response.

**Component #2: `FeedbackComponent`**
Simple form to send data to the server (Feedback)

If I'm doing a HTTP call in `ProcessDataComponent` (i.e., Button Click event to trigger the HTTP Call), immediately I'm navigating to Feedback. I can't able to get the processed result data. Because the said component gets destroy and loads with the component `FeedbackComponent`

I need to trigger the HTTP call in `ProcessDataComponent` and this should perform the HTTP call in background irrespective of routing. Kindly help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the call inside `ProcessDataComponent` you can make it inside `AppComponent` (the one that holds the entire app). This component is long-lived and it won't be destroyed on navigation. The way to listen for the button click (to trigger the request) should probably be through a service.

Here's a quick [demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzjkwr).